# Drawing a horizontal axis for size comparison

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a collection of tuples `(itemname, size)` and would like to visualize their sizes on a horizontal axis which is log-scaled. Ideally a line would connect a label showing `itemname` to the x-coordinate representing `size` on the axis. Labels should be nicely arranged on one or both sides of the axis.

What are my options for plotting this with Python?

This is what I came up with based on your suggestions:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,6))

for i, (name, radius) in enumerate(objects):
    sgn = 2 * (i % 2) - 1
    ax.annotate(name, xy=(radius,0), xytext=(radius,sgn* (0.5 + random.randint(1,12) * 0.1)), ha='center',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc,angleA=0,armA=30,rad=30", facecolor='gray'),
               color="Maroon")
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(1.e1,1.e15)
ax.set_ylim(0,4)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axhline(color='k', lw=1)
ax.plot([obj[1] for obj in objects], [0]*len(objects), 'ob', markersize=2)
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.tick_params(length=8)
ax.set_xlabel('edges')
seaborn.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I could hide the y-axis it would be done. Adding `fig.axes[0].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something you could try with [`annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate), though the appearance could be tweaked a little. To stop the labels overlapping, I simply put them on alternating sides of the x-axis, but depending on your data you might need something more sophisticated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = [ ('Earth', 6.371e6),
            ('Jupiter', 6.9911e7),
            ('Sun', 6.96e8),
            ('Pollux', 5.568e9),
            ('Arcturus', 1.789e10),
            ('Aldebaran', 3.076e10),
            ('Antares', 6.14568e11)
          ]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, (name, radius) in enumerate(objects):
    sgn = 2 * (i % 2) - 1
    ax.annotate(name, xy=(radius,0), xytext=(radius,sgn*1), ha='center',
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),)

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(1.e6,1.e12)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)

ax.axhline(color='k', lw=3)
ax.plot([obj[1] for obj in objects], [0]*len(objects), 'or', markersize=10)
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_xlabel('Radius /m')
plt.show()
```

[image]